# How to anonymize the programs from the terminal?

Tags: onion-services, linux

How to anonymize the programs from your terminal (such as `wget`, `curl`, etc.)?

Comment: curl
/usr/bin/torify: torsocks not found in your PATH. Perhaps it isn't installed? (tsocks is no longer supported, for security reasons.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Torify** is a simple wrapper that attempts to find the best underlying Tor wrapper available on a system. It calls torsocks or tsocks with a tor specific configuration file.

It'll take measures to ensure that an application, which has not been designed for use with Tor (such as TorChat), will use only Tor for internet connectivity. Also ensure that there are no leaks from DNS, UDP or [the application protocol](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO#examplesandreasoningfortheWARNING).

You should read the documentation at ​[Tor Project](https://www.torproject.org) before attempting to "torify" any applications your self.

---

**Installation**

Torify should be already installed with your Tor server.

If not, you've to install tor, which is usually found on all the repository so for Debian, Ubuntu and Mint you just have to type:

```
sudo apt-get install tor
```

On OSX with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/): `brew install tor torsocks`

After installation and configuration, and starting the tor server, you can prefix `torify` before any command.

---

Example usages:

```
$ torify curl ifconfig.me
$ torify wget -r --mirror -S http://dppmfxaacucguzpc.onion
$ torify links http://dppmfxaacucguzpc.onion/
```

Read more:

- [Tor Installation guides](https://www.torproject.org/docs/installguide.html.en)
- [Torify HOWTO](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO)
- [How to anonymize the programs from your terminal with torify](http://linuxaria.com/howto/how-to-anonymize-the-programs-from-your-terminal-with-torify)

Comment: Yeah, torify is fine with e.g. telnet, netcat. Don't attempt to use torify with something like p2p, e.g. bittorrent, it will either not work, or deanonymise you, or probably both.